Why does the error is always logical NOT when MWPM fails?
Consider the decoding of noisy syndrome using pymatching (as shown here) for the repetition code. The logical operator in this case is simply identity matrix. One could write the python code as
def repetition_stabilisers(N):
    check_matrix = np.zeros((N-1, N), dtype=int)
    for i in range(N-1):
        check_matrix[i, i] = 1
        check_matrix[i, i+1] = 1
    return check_matrix

def x_logicals(L):
    return np.eye(L,dtype = int) # np.ones((1,L),dtype = int)

L = 10
repetitions = L
H = repetition_stabilisers(L)
logicals = x_logicals(L)

num_stabilisers, num_qubits = H.shape
num_errors = 0
for i in range(num_shots):
    noise_new = (np.random.rand(num_qubits, repetitions) < p).astype(np.uint8)
    noise_cumulative = (np.cumsum(noise_new, 1) % 2).astype(np.uint8)
    noise_total = noise_cumulative[:,-1]
    syndrome = H@noise_cumulative % 2
    syndrome_error = (np.random.rand(num_stabilisers, repetitions) < q).astype(np.uint8)
    syndrome_error[:,-1] = 0 # Perfect measurements in last round to ensure even parity
    noisy_syndrome = (syndrome + syndrome_error) % 2
    # Convert to difference syndrome
    noisy_syndrome[:,1:] = (noisy_syndrome[:,1:] - noisy_syndrome[:,0:-1]) % 2
    predicted_logicals_flipped = matching.decode(noisy_syndrome)
    actual_logicals_flipped = noise_total@logicals.T % 2
    if not np.array_equal(predicted_logicals_flipped, actual_logicals_flipped):
        num_errors += 1

Interestingly, if you consider the cases where it fails, I found that the predicted logical flipped are exactly logical NOT of correct logical flipped. Is there any particular reason for this?

If the data qubits were not all 0 or all 1, there would be detection events still present in the system. The decoder predicts corrections that remove all detection events, and therefore forces the system into the all-0 or all-1 state.

Hi, I'm trying to understand what you mean here. If I understood correctly, you are saying that the decoder always predict such that a arbitrary state would results in $\psi = \alpha |0\rangle^{\otimes N} + \beta |1\rangle^{\otimes N}$ or $\psi = \beta |0\rangle^{\otimes N} + \alpha |1\rangle^{\otimes N}$ (basically projecting onto the code space).

Yes, the decoder always projects onto the code space.

Is it still be true in case of measurement errors?

Yes. The logical $X$ measurement is inferred from transversally measuring the data qubits and does not involve any measurement qubits. Any SPAM error during readout is equivalently a data qubit error. Using the measurement outcomes, we can construct an error syndrome and classically repair the incorrect measurement, returning to the codespace before deducing $\bar{X}$.

@RohanMehta To be honest, I didn't get that. Can you explain why you taking logical $X$ measurement and what do you mean by data qubits? If you could explain in a bit detail?

@Himanshu if your detectors are declared correctly, it is also true of measurement errors. If they are declared incorrectly, the system isn't fault tolerant to begin with.

@CraigGidney I still did not get that. Consider the limiting case where the measurement errors are sufficient large, in that case, I don't seem to see how you can still go to your code space. For example, if you are in the code space to begin with, and let's say your got wrong syndrome, then you will end up out side code space after the correction operator.

@Himanshu then go try it and be amazed
